# Lisp: How to print out the recursive function to print each item in the list and sublist without quotes and return the number of items?

Tags: recursion, lisp, common-lisp

I want my function to print each item in the list and sublist without quotes and return the number of items. The output of the list also needs to be in order, but my function is printing in reverse. I'm not sure why, is there any reasons why? Any suggestions to how I can recursively count the number of items and return that number? In addition why is the last item printed is supposed to be 9.99 instead of 100.999?

Edit: Thanks for the help so far. Just last question: Is there a way to make any output like DAY to be in lower case (day), or is that something that can't be done?

My function:

```
(defun all-print (inlist)
    (cond
        ((not (listp inlist)) 
            (format t "Error, arg must be a list, returning nil")
            ())          
        ((null inlist) 0) 
        ((listp (car inlist)) 
            (ffn (append (car inlist)(cdr inlist))))
        (t
            (format t "~a " (car inlist) (ffn (cdr inlist))))))
```

My output example:

```
CL-USER 1 >  (all-print (list 5 "night" 3 (list 9 -10) (quote day) -5.9 (* 100.999)))
100.999 -5.9 DAY -10 9 3 night 5 
NIL
```

What it's suppose to output example:

```
5 night 3 9 -10 day -5.9 9.99 ;print
8 ;returns
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `all-print` is supposed to be called `ffn`, since it looks like those are supposed to be recursive calls.  In the rest of this answer,  I'm just going to use `ffn` since it's shorter.

### Why the output is in reverse

At present, your final `cond` clause makes the recursive call *before* doing any printing, because your recursive call is an argument to `format`:

```
(format t "~a " (car inlist) (ffn (cdr inlist)))
;               ------------ -----------------
;                     3rd          4th
```

All the arguments to `format`, including the 4th in this case, are evaluated before format is called.  The 4th argument here will print the *rest* of the list, and then `format` will finally print the first element of the list. Your last `cond` clause should do the printing, and *then* make the recursive call:

```
(cond 
  …
  (t
    (format t "~a " (car inlist))
    (ffn (cdr inlist))))
```

### Why you get 100.999 rather than 9.99

You're getting 100.999 in your output rather than 9.99 (or something close to it) because the value of `(* 100.999)` is simply the value of `100.999`.  I'm guessing that you wanted `(* 10 0.999)` (note the space between `10` and `0.99`).  That still won't be quite `9.99` because of floating point arithmetic, though, but it will be close.

### How to get the number of elements printed

[uselpa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22351279/1281433) provides a good solution here.  If you're supposed to return the number of elements printed, then *every* return value from this function should be a number.  You have four cases,

- not a list — returning `nil` is not a great idea. If this can't return a number (e.g., 0), then signal a real error (e.g., with `(error "~A is not a list" inlist)`.
- inlist is empty — return 0 (you already do)
- `(car inlist)` is a list — here you make a recursive call to `ffn`.  Since the contract says that it will return a count, you're fine.  This is one of the reasons that it's so important in the first case (not a list) that you don't return a non-number; the contract depends on every call that returns returning an number.
- In the final case, you print one item, and then make a recursive call to `ffn`.  That recursive call returns the number of remaining elements that are printed, and since you just printed one, you need to add one to it.  Thus the final `cond` clause should actually be something like the following.  (Adding one to something is so common that Common Lisp has a [`1+`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_1pl_1_.htm) function.)

  ```
  (cond 
    …
    (t
      (format t "~a " (car inlist))
      (1+ (ffn (cdr inlist)))))     ; equivalent to (+ 1 (ffn (cdr inlist)))
  ```

### A more efficient solution

We've addressed the issues with your original code, but we can also ask whether there are better approaches to the problem.

#### Don't append

Notice that when you have input like `((a b c) d e f)`, you create the list `(a b c d e f)` and recurse on it.  However, you could equivalently recurse on `(a b c)` and on `(d e f)`, and add the results together.  This would avoid creating a new list with `append`.

#### Don't check argument types

You're checking that the input is a list, but there's really not much need to do that.  If the input isn't a list, then using list processing functions on it will signal a similar error.

#### A new version

This is somewhat similar to [uselpa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22351279/1281433), but I've made some different choices about how to handle certain things.  I use a local function `process-element` to handle elements from each input list.  If the element is a list, then we pass it to `print-all` recursively, and return the result of the recursive call.  Otherwise we return one and print the value.  (I used `(prog1 1 …)` to emphasize that we're returning one, and printing is just a side effect.  The main part of `print-all` is a typical recursion now.

```
(defun print-all (list)
  (flet ((process-element (x)
           (if (listp x)
               (print-all x)
               (prog1 1
                 (format t "~A " x)))))
    (if (endp list)
        0
        (+ (process-element (first list))
           (print-all (rest list))))))
```

Of course, now that we've pulled out the auxiliary function, the iteration is a bit clearer, and we see that it's actually a case for [`reduce`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_reduce.htm).  You might even choose to do away with the local function, and just use a lambda function:

```
(defun print-all (list)
  (reduce '+ list
          :key (lambda (x)
                 (if (listp x)
                     (print-all x)
                     (prog1 1
                       (format t "~A " x))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my suggestion on how to write this function:

```
(defun all-print (lst)
  (if (null lst)
    0                    ; empty list => length is 0
    (let ((c (car lst))) ; bind first element to c
      (if (listp c)      ; if it's a list
        (+ (all-print c) (all-print (cdr lst))) ; recurse down + process the rest of the list
        (progn           ; else
          (format t "~a " c)              ; not a list -> print item, then
          (1+ (all-print (cdr lst)))))))) ; add 1 and process the rest of the list
```

then

```
? (all-print (list 5 "night" 3 (list 9 -10) (quote day) -5.9 (* 100.999)))
5 night 3 9 -10 DAY -5.9 100.999 
8
```